# Why did Ultron want a flesh body?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, the titular robot compels a Korean scientist to make him a body into which he plans to transfer his consciousness. Why? Such a body would seem to make him vulnerable to the very plot he plans to destroy all life on earth.

Comment: One could hardly argue that superman's body (for example) is vulnerable to much. I don't think the body they were creating was necessarily truly "human"... but it's ambiguous.

Comment: I'm guessing to move the plot forward.

Comment: flesh body? using vibranium?

Comment: Actually Ultron's body was vulnerable in his current form with Iron Man technology (he gets some damage during the fights). He compels the scientist to modify the machine that creates human tissues to create a body out of vibranium. Ultron is basically all over the internet, but he needs a physical form strong enough to fight the Avengers and whatever else stands in his way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All that matters to Ultron was to expand his power to fight the Avengers so that he could do what he wants. To increase his power, he wanted that body out of vibranium, which we have seen in the movie was very powerful (in a constructive way). If Ultron's experiment had not been interrupted by the Avengers, it could had made him as powerful as the Vision.